# Where [column] Like 'X' is not returning the same results as Where [column] = 'X' in Oracle

Tags: oracle

Very strange occurence occuring in my Oracle DB.

When I run these two queries, in theory they should return the same results. Right?

```
select * from table  where column = 'word_word'

select * from table  where column like 'word_word'
```

However this is not the case. I am only getting results when I use the '=' operator. Could it have anything to do with the Oracle versions?

EDIT: After a quick google I can see the it must be the underscore that is causing the issue. Still not sure why this would be happening in one server but not the other

Comment: What's the actual query?  Might `word` have an underscore or a percent sign in it?  Those are wildcards in Oracle.

Comment: Oh yes does have underscores, actually. However it should also be noted that in my test environment they both return the same results.

After a quick google I can see the it must be the underscore that is causing the issue. Still not sure why this would be happening in on one server but not the other

Comment: What is the data type of the column?  What does `select dump(column_name)` return?  Are there NLS differences (i.e. one session is trying to do a case-insensitive comparison)?